# Get Value of array, or i think its dictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, json, dictionary

wanna ask about json and dictioary also array

now i've json data like this

```
{
  data: [
          {

            featured: true,
            price: {
                        currency: "IDR",
                        amount: 5557679,
                        formatted: "Rp5.558.000"
          },
    ]
}
```

and this is my syntax to call this

```
NSArray* deals_global_json = [json objectForKey:@"data"]; //2
          if(deals_global_json!=NULL){

              for (int i=0;i<[deals_global_json count];i++){

                  NSDictionary* jsonData = [deals_global_json objectAtIndex:i];

                  NSString *featured=[jsonData objectForKey:@"featured"];
                  NSArray *price=[jsonData objectForKey:@"price"];
                  NSDictionary *formatted =[price objectAtIndex:0];


              }
```

and it error, how to parse price array like that?

Comment: Please provide what kind of error you have. "It error" does not really help (and isn't even proper english), is it compilation error, runtime error, which error message, or no error but just nil object…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong in your code:

> NSDictionary *formatted =[price objectAtIndex:0];

because price is a Dictionary.

You can use:

```
NSString *currency = [price objectForKey:@"currency"];
NSString *amount = [price objectForKey:@"amount"];
NSString *formatted = [price objectForKey:@"formatted"];
```

The difference between {...} and [...]:

- the first one is Object (an unordered collection of key:value pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value, comma-separated and enclosed in curly braces; the keys must be strings and should be distinct from each other);
- the second one is Array (an ordered sequence of values, comma-separated and enclosed in square brackets; the values do not need to be of the same type).

To understand, how it works, you can read more about JSON:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: so ? can u explain the right way?

Comment: haey... its greattt thanks man...

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, accept it as the right answer